# how to find count of rows for this sql query?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$common_query_string = "Select a.INC_KEY,a.STATE, a.FDID, a.INC_DATE, a.INC_NO, a.EXP_NO, concat(a.NUM_MILE,' ', a.STREET_PRE,' ', a.STREETNAME,' ', a.STREETTYPE,' ',
          a.STREETSUF, ' ',a.APT_NO,' ', a.CITY,' ', a.STATE_ID,' ', a.ZIP5,' ', a.ZIP4) as address, a.latitude, a.longitude, 
          ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( a.latitude ) )
          * cos( radians( a.longitude ) - radians($lon) ) 
          + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( a.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance,
          a.INC_TYPE, a.FF_DEATH, a.OTH_DEATH, a.PROP_LOSS , a.CONT_LOSS,(b.CODE_DESCR) as INC_CODE_DESC, (d.CODE_DESCR) as CAUSE_CODE_DESC";


    $query = sprintf("$common_query_string ,'nfirs' as SOURCE
      From
        (Select * From incident
        Where latitude > '%s' And latitude < '%s' 
        And longitude > '%s' And longitude < '%s' %s) 
        As a , codelookup b,codelookup d
  Where a.INC_TYPE = b.code_value AND b.fieldid = 'INC_TYPE' 
  And  a.CAUSE_IGN  = d.code_value AND  d.fieldid = 'CAUSE_IGN'
      having distance < '%s'
       ", mysql_real_escape_string($minLat), mysql_real_escape_string($maxLat), mysql_real_escape_string($minLon), mysql_real_escape_string($maxLon), mysql_real_escape_string($query_condition), mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
```

Comment: `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` might be helpfule here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql_num_rows($result); 

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable your join yourcondition;

you have to use this :

 *$final_Query='select count(*)as count from ('.$query.')*

and palce this below
Where a.INC_TYPE = b.code_value AND b.fieldid = 'INC_TYPE' 
And  a.CAUSE_IGN  = d.code_value AND  d.fieldid = 'CAUSE_IGN'
having distance < '%s, mysql_real_escape_string($minLat), mysql_real_escape_string($maxLat), mysql_real_escape_string($minLon), mysql_real_escape_string($maxLon), mysql_real_escape_string($query_condition), mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
```

Answer (score 1):

As you're using the older `mysql_` methods, you can use [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows) after you've executed the query:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

*Side Note* (`mysql_` methods are being deprecated)
I would suggest refactoring your code to use the recommended [`mysqli_`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) methods instead. You can perform the same types of queries in both, but updating will grant you the ability to object-oriented style code, prepared statements which can help improve readability, and also further secure your code against SQL-injection.

Here's the same count-syntax with [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/mysqli_num_rows):

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbLink, $query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

**UPDATE** (counting directly in the query)
To get a total number of rows directly in the query, you can use MySQL's [`COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM
    (Select * From incident Where latitude > '%s' And latitude < '%s' And longitude > '%s' And longitude < '%s' %s) As a, codelookup b,codelookup d
WHERE
    a.INC_TYPE = b.code_value AND b.fieldid = 'INC_TYPE' AND  a.CAUSE_IGN  = d.code_value AND  d.fieldid = 'CAUSE_IGN'
HAVING
    distance < '%s'
```

Comment: Any other way such as to find count inside the sql query?

Comment: @JimBozZ Other than `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...`? I've never heard of `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` from the other answer, but using `COUNT(*)` hasn't failed me before.

Comment: @newfurniturey  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS returns full count of the table even we apply limit that is the difference

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_num_rows($result);
```

gives you the number of selected rows by the query result.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable your join yourcondition;
```

Get total rows when LIMIT is used...

If you'd used a LIMIT clause but want to know how many rows you'd get without it, use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS in your query, followed by SELECT FOUND_ROWS();

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS FROM yourtable your join yourcondition 
   LIMIT 10;

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Comment: Any other way such as to find count inside the sql query?